# Major differences in CSS design for IE6 & Other browsers

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

This might sound to be a big question, but could you specify what are the **issues** to be considered which designing CSS for **IE6** & Other browsers.

To be in more simple terms, what is so different in CSS for IE6 when compared with other standard browsers. **What are the Issues to be considered when making a IE6 compatible CSS**

Comment: Coding CSS for IE6 involves large amounts of cursing.

Comment: I dint get the question listed when i posted, thats why got it duped, sorry :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://davidwalsh.name/6-reasons-why-ie6-must-die

What are the Issues to be considered when making a IE6 compatible CSS?

Don't do it. Time to move on. Do you still design for Netscape 4 css too?

http://code.google.com/p/ie6-upgrade-warning/

Comment: Usually it's clients wanting IE6 because the IE6 is the standard browser in the organization. A standard that never changes because it would cost money to do so.

Comment: @fforw IE6 has 24 unpatched vulnerabilities in as of February 9, 2010. These vulnerabilities, which include several "moderately critical" ratings, amount to 17% of the total 144 security risks. Organizations which don't update are exposing themselves to unnecessary risks that would cost money, too. http://secunia.com/advisories/product/11/ By refusing to support IE6, this encourages organizations to upgrade if their users cannot use a larger proportion of websites.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to have a look at:

**[Dealing with IE6 CSS Bugs](http://www.debonstudio.com/blog/dealing-with-ie6-css-bugs/)**

**More Resource:**

**[Universal Internet Explorer 6 CSS](http://forabeautifulweb.com/blog/about/universal_internet_explorer_6_css/)**

Answer (score 0):

[Explorer Exposed](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer.html) is a good reference who summarize most of the IE bugs